# How look this HTML and JS on Next.Js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sass, next.js

Here's an example of how it should be: codepen.io/j0be/pen/jWGVvV

How look this HTML and JS on Next.Js?

I want to make this cod on Next.js width TypeScript and SCSS!
But I don't know how  transform the HTML and the JavaScript on Next.js with using TypeScript and SCSS. Please help me!!!

The my JavaScript:

```
$('.dropdown-el').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  $('#'+$(e.target).attr('for')).prop('checked',true);
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.dropdown-el').removeClass('expanded');
});
```

Me need make my input select is custom and when I opened my select. The my select is beautiful
The my HTML:

```
<span class="dropdown-el">
    <input type="radio" name="sortType" value="Relevance" checked="checked" id="sort-relevance"><label for="sort-relevance">Relevance</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sortType" value="Popularity" id="sort-best"><label for="sort-best">Product Popularity</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sortType" value="PriceIncreasing" id="sort-low"><label for="sort-low">Price Low to High</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sortType" value="PriceDecreasing" id="sort-high"><label for="sort-high">Price High to Low</label>
    
  </span>
```

The my SCSS:

```
$color:#3694d7;
$timing:.3s;

body {
  text-align:center;
  background:mix($color,#fff,10%);
  min-height:95vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border-bottom: 5vh solid $color;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro","Arial",sans;
  font-size:24px;
}
.dropdown-el {
  margin-top:20vh;
    
  min-width: 12em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-height: 2em;
  max-height:2em;
  overflow:hidden;
  top: .5em;  
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #444;
  
  outline: none;
  border: .06em solid transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: mix($color,#fff,25%);
  
  transition: $timing all ease-in-out;
  input:focus + label {
    background: #def;
  }
  input {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.01;
  }
  label {
    border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
    display:block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: $timing color ease-in-out;  
    &:nth-child(2) {
      margin-top: 2em;
      border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
    }
  }
  input:checked + label {
    display:block;
    border-top: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

    &:nth-child(2) {
      margin-top: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
  
  &::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.8em;
    top: 0.9em;
    border: .3em solid $color;
    border-color: $color transparent transparent transparent;
    transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
  }
  &.expanded {
    border: .06em solid $color;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: .25em;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px 3px 5px 0px;
    max-height:15em;
    
    label {
      border-top: .06em solid #d9d9d9;
      &:hover {
        color:$color;
      }
    }
    input:checked + label {
      color:$color;
    }
    
    &::after {
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
      top:.55em;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's an example of how it should be: codepen.io/j0be/pen/jWGVvV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did **CODESANDBOX** with your code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-volhard-dgbrym?file=/src/App.tsx

> I've used the useForm hook for better manipulation. You can explore this hook to improve the form control: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/

**TS REACT CODE**

```js
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

interface IFormInput {
  sortType: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<IFormInput>();

  const onSubmit = (data: IFormInput) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="dropdown-el">
        <input
          {...register("sortType")}
          type="radio"
          value="Relevance"
          checked
          id="sort-relevance"
        />
        <label htmlFor="sort-relevance">Relevance</label>
        <input
          {...register("sortType")}
          type="radio"
          value="Popularity"
          id="sort-best"
        />
        <label htmlFor="sort-best">Product Popularity</label>
        <input
          {...register("sortType")}
          type="radio"
          value="PriceIncreasing"
          id="sort-low"
        />
        <label htmlFor="sort-low">Price Low to High</label>
        <input
          {...register("sortType")}
          type="radio"
          value="PriceDecreasing"
          id="sort-high"
        />
        <label htmlFor="sort-high">Price High to Low</label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very close to the desired result. But here's an example of how it should be: https://codepen.io/j0be/pen/jWGVvV

Comment: I am using your the cod, but I get error: TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useForm) is not a function; Only I used import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";  Help me please!!!!

Comment: Hello Arthur, I'll help, but I need some time because I'm at work.
We can achieve this result but think differently from JS/JQuery because React will use states and other stuff.

Comment: Hello! I want to ask you how change value of select? Please help me!